# Ionic 2 'indexOf' of null error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

in ionic application I'm getting error Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null.

Here is my html code

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)" [ngClass]="cart.indexOf(item)>=-1 ? 'active' : 'none'">
      <p >{{ item }}</p>
        </button> 
</ion-list>
```

And ts code

```
itemSelected(item: string) {
if (this.cart.indexOf(item) == -1) {
  this.cart.push(item);
  this.isActive = true;
}else{
  this.cart.splice(this.cart.indexOf(item),1);
  this.isActive = false;
}
this.storage.set('cart', cart);}
```

Above I declare

```
public cart: string[] = [];


ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.cart = this.storage.get('cart').then((val) => {
      return this.cart = val;
   });
}
```

I want on click on item to change ngClass and save cart in storage.

Comment: try `[ngClass]="cart.includes(item) ? 'active' : 'none'"`

Comment: can you console log `val`? also no need to set `this.storage.get()` call to `this.cart`

Comment: when are you getting this error? On page loading or after clicking on element?

Comment: On page load. When I comment `return this.cart = val;` everything is working

Comment: @ErikGern try this: `[ngClass]="cart?.indexOf(item)>=-1 ? 'active' : 'none'"` (add a question mark after cart)

Comment: @porgo Thanks, that works

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning twice `this.cart`? Check value for null before assigning.

Try modify you code like below.

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.storage.get('cart').then((val) => {
      if(val)
        this.cart = val;
   });
}
```